# How to rewrite this constructor to calculate a class filed using inner static value?

Tags: dart

How to change this constructor so that the `link` would be `_host + link` ?

```
class Profile {
  static final String _host = 'http://github.com';

  Profile(this.link, this.id, this.photo);

  final link;
  final id;
  final photo;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '$link, $id, $photo';
  }
}
```

Comment: `Profile(String link, this.id, this.photo) : link = _host + link;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't since [writting `this.link` is equivalent to writing the following class](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors):

```
class Profile {
  static final String _host = 'http://github.com';

  Profile(String link, this.id, this.photo) :
    this.link = link;

  final link;
  final id;
  final photo;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '$link, $id, $photo';
  }
}
```

And link being final, you can't assign it to any other value. Your best option here you be to do somthing like this:

```
class Profile {
  static final String _host = 'http://github.com';

  Profile(String path, this.id, this.photo) :
    link = _host + path;

  final link;
  final id;
  final photo;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '$link, $id, $photo';
  }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to rename the constructor's parameter.

Comment: I agree that technically it's not needed. However from a readability point of view I find it weird to name a variable in the constructor and them immediately change its value. I think it's better practice to chose a different name.